# Let G be a group of order 12. Does the group of automorphisms of G contain an element of order 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $12$. Does $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ contain an element of order $5$?

I have tried using Sylow Theorems to obtain (G has only one Sylow 2-subgroup (order 4) or G has only one Sylow 3-subgroup (order 3)), G is not simple. And I was trying to construct some group actions, but these seem to lead me to nowhere.

Comment: I have tried using Sylow Theorems to obtain (G has only one Sylow 2-subgroup (order 4) or G has only one Sylow 3-subgroup (order 3)), G is not simple.  And I was trying to construct a homomorphism between G and Aut(G), but these seem to lead me to nowhere.  Do you have any idea? @DanielMcLaury

Comment: If there is a technique that applies directly to all groups $G$ of order $12$, then it probably concerns the orbits of elements in $G$ under the action generated by the putative automorphism (group isomorphism of $G$) having order $5$.  How can two such orbits intersect?

Comment: Intersection of any two orbits (equivalence classes) should give an empty set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an argument that works for all groups of order $12$.

Suppose that $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(G)$ of order $5$ with $|G|=12$. Since the elements in $G$ that are fixed by $\alpha$ form a subgroup, $\alpha$ must act on the  elements of $G$ with two orbits of length $5$ and fixed subgroup of order $2$.

The elements in the same orbit have the same order, and there exist elements of order $3$. The total number of elements of order $3$ is even, so there must be $10$ such, but that would give $5$ Sylow $3$-subgroups, contradicting Sylow's theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "the automorphism" in the second paragraph?
What is the action you defined in the same paragraph?

Comment: I meant a putative automorphism of order $5$. I have edited to clarify.  You don't have to use Sylow's theorem, because if there was a unique fixed element of order $2$ then it would be in $Z(G)$ and so there would be elements of order $6$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The following summarized how I followed your thought, please let me know if you see any problem.  
You were considering a group action $$\phi :<\alpha> \times G \to G:(\alpha,g)\mapsto \alpha (g)$$.  By Orbit-stabilizer Theorem, the number of elements in each orbit should be 1 or 5.  So $$12=5+5+1+1 ---(1)$$, or $$12=5+1+1+1+1+1+1+1---(2)$$, or $$12=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1---(3)$$.  Eqn $(3)$ means any elements in $<\alpha>$ is the identity map, contradiction. Eqn $(2)$ is also not possible because 7 does not divide 12.
By Sylow Theorem, there exists element of order 3.

Comment: But why is the number of elements of order 3 even?

Comment: And are you suggesting two ways of solving the problem? One requires the use of Sylow's Theorem as mentioned in your Answer, the other does not require Sylow's Theorem as stated in your comment?

Comment: You should be able to prove for yourself that the number of elements of order $3$ is even. Yes, I was pointing out that it can be done without Sylow's theorem, although you need Cauchy's theorem for the existence of an element of order $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think I finally solved the problem using your approach that requires Sylow's theorem.  By Sylow's Theorem, the number of Sylow $3$-subgroup(s) is either one or four.  By Lagrange's Theorem, the intersection of any two Sylow $3$-subgroups contains only the identity element.  Thus in both cases, the number of elements of order 3 is even.  

However, for another approach without using Sylow's theorem, why would the unique element of order 2 be in $Z(G)$?

Comment: Because it must be equal to all of its conjugates.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think I got what you meant on this part, but I still have two questions.  For the argument without using Sylow's theorem, if there was a unique element, $x$, of order 2, for any $g$ in $G$, $gxg^{-1}$ is also of order $2$, since it is unique, $gxg^{-1}=x$, so $g\in Z(G)$.  By Cauchy's Theorem, since $3$ is a prime that divides $12$, $G$ has an element of order $3$.  Thus there exists $xg$ as an element of order $6$.  My first question: Is the contradiction here due to that only one orbit (of order $5$) contains $xg$ (an element of order $6$), which is not possible?

Comment: My second question: What if there did not have a unique fixed element of order $2$? What would be the contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

Take for example the cyclic group of order $\;12\;$ :

$$\text{Aut}\,(C_{12})\cong C_{12}^*\cong C_3^*\times C_4^*\cong C_2\times C_2$$

and thus we don't even have an element of order five.

Or even simpler using another approach: it is always true that $\;|\text{Aut}\,(C_n)|=\phi(n)\;,\;\;\phi=$ Euler's Totien Functions, so for the cyclic group of order $\;12\;$ we have $\;\phi(12)=\phi(3)\phi(4)=2\cdot2=4\;$ , and a group of order four cannot have an element of order five (why?).

Comment: G is not required to be a cyclic group.

Comment: For the (why?) It could be explained by the Theorem of Lagrange, 5 does not divide 6.

Comment: @user387597 I know it is not required the group is a cyclic one: I only proveded you with an example of a group of order twelve which doesn't fulfill what you ask about, and you're right about Lagrange.

Comment: @user26857 Of course. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. @DonAntonio

Answer (score 1):

With the hints and guidance from some helpful teaching assistants, I came up with the following:

Let H be the cyclic subgroup generated by an automorphism on G of order 5, let X be the set of all Sylow 2-subgroups of G, Y be the set of all Sylow 3-subgroups of G.  A group action of H on X is trivial.  So another action of H on a fixed point (that is a Sylow 2-subgroup, denote it by $P_2$) of X could be defined and the second action is also trivial.  So H fixed at least four elements of order 2 in G.  For the remaining elements in G that belong to a Sylow 3-subgroup, $P_3$ of G, the elements are as well fixed by H. Since any automorphism in H is a homomorphism, H also fixes elements in $P_2 \cdot P_3$. Thus any automorphism in H actually fixes all elements in G, and is thus an identity map.  An identity map in Aut(G) is of order one, not of order five.  Contradiction arises.